# Test_helper for a loop in the view in Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rubygems

This code loops through and prints the entire hash, but if the size of the hash is greater than 4MB, it iterates over the first ten elements only.

```
<% sections_content.each do |title, summary| %>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;"><%= raw title %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= raw summary %></td>
    </tr>
    <% break if ObjectSpace.memsize_of(sections_content) > 4194304 && index == 9 %>
<% end %>
```

I want to write a test for it to ensure the loop breaks when the index is equal to 9, which means it loops over the first ten elements.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
test "should size> 400" do
  assert_equal(9, index, [msg])
end
```

The test doesn't work. Any help for a better method to test this code [sic]

Answer (score 1):

In order to *unit test* this properly, you need to first make it more *testable*. Move the relevant code into a helper method, and then test that method; don't just cram all of your logic inside the view.

In other words, create a helper method (perhaps somewhere in `./app/helpers/`):

```
def section_summaries(sections_content)
  sections_content.map.with_index do |title, summary, index|
    # Generate HTML code...
    break if ObjectSpace.memsize_of(sections_content) > 4194304 && index == 9
  end
end
```

Then in your view, call the helper method:

```
<%= section_summaries(sections_content) %>
```

And in your spec, test the helper method directly:

```
require 'test_helper'
test "only show first 10 summaries for large dataset" do
  assert_equal(10, section_summaries(sections_content).length)
end
```

This is only a rough guide; your actual implementation may differ slightly. The key point to take away is try to isolate logic into methods/classes for unit testability.

Comment: Thank's a lot , the problem is this is a gem a notification gem , the file structure is a bit different .
here's the source code for it : https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification
I would appreciate it a lot if you take take a look

Comment: I presume you're talking about [this file](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/c745491a10c193cfba43d44ba00d1dd39f5be71c/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/exception_notification.html.erb)? It shouldn't make a difference -- since you're overriding that file anyway, you can add whatever helper methods you like.

Comment: Although with that said, I do find your implementation a little odd... Why not just limit `@sections` to be at most 10 (or whatever) elements big, and leave the view file alone?